# onServiceConnected is not called when implement IDownloaderClient

Tags: android

I followed the examples: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html to add service to download APK Expansion files.

BaseActivity implements IDownloaderClient which overrides onServiceConnected 
[image: Base Activity]
[image]

I also have 2 files for Service and edit Manifest for it:[image]
[image]
[image]

**The problem is onServiceConnected has never been called. How to resolve it?**